# How can I create an array of NSNumbers from a text file?

Tags: ios, objective-c, file, nsarray, nsnumber

I'm testing a sorting algorithm and I have different text files containing values like the following.

```
2345

6789

4567
```

I've tried something like this.

```
NSString *title = @"test";
NSString *type = @"rtf";

NSMutableArray *test4 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:title ofType:type]];
```

but the result is a (null) array.

I understand that at some point I have to convert those values into `NSNumber` objects but I'm a little bit lost with Objective-C.

Can somebody give me some advice?

Comment: Did you NSLog the array, to see what you got?

Comment: (Keep in mind that arrayWithContentsOfFile is not likely to make much sense of an RTF file, if RTF means Rich Text Format.  arrayWithContentsOfFile is only intended to read Apple's property list files.)

Comment: but should work with a txt?

Comment: If the txt file is formatted like a property list file.

Comment: and does it automatically retrieves that is a NSNumber?

Comment: how is formatted a property list file?

Comment: ok thx a lot i found how to format it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [`NSScanner`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSScanner_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSString *filename = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:title ofType:type];
NSString *fileContents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filename encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
if (error) NSLog(@"%s: stringWithContentsOfFile error: %@", __FUNCTION__, error);
NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:fileContents];

NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];
NSInteger i;
while ([scanner scanInt:&i]) {
    [array addObject:@(i)];
}
```

For discussion about scanners, reading files into strings, and general string programming, see the [String Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/introStrings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000035i).

Answer (score 0):

If you change the extension to `.txt` (of course save it from as plain text) you could read them.

I wrote some code for the case when you put the numbers one under another

```
1234

2344

2345
```

Here the code I'm using.

```
NSString *title = @"test";
NSString *type = @"txt";

NSString *file = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:title ofType:type] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
NSArray *numberList = [[file stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]]componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];

NSMutableArray *test4 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
int lastItem = 0; 

for (NSString *listItem in numberList)
{
   //this is added because you most surely have a \n as last item and it will convert to 0
   if(lastItem < listItem.count - 1)
   [test4 addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:listItem.integerValue]];
   lastItem++;
}
```